# Irrationality of $\sqrt 2$ using induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

I came upon this exercise in a textbook.

I know that $\frac{n}{b} \ne \sqrt{2} $ for all $b \gt 0$ and $n \le N_0$.
How can I then show that $\frac{N_0 + 1}{b} \ne \sqrt{2}$ for all $b \gt 0$?

Comment: Which textbook?

Comment: This is the textbook: http://www.amazon.com/Discrete-Mathematics-Applications-Kenneth-Rosen/dp/0072880082/ref=dp_ob_image_bk

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $$\frac{N_{0}+1}{b}=\sqrt{2}\rightarrow (N_{0}+1)^{2}=2b^{2}$$

Obviously $N_{0}+1>b$ or $N_{0} \geq b$.

We can see that $N_{0}+1$ is divisible by 2. Let $N_{0}+1=2t$ $$4t^2=2b^2\ \rightarrow\ 2t^{2}=b^{2}\ \rightarrow\ \frac{b}{t}=\sqrt{2}$$

Hence we have found a number $b\leq N_{0}$ such that the given condition holds true which is a contradiction!

Comment: This is essentially the classical proof by cancelling $2,\,$ see the Remark in my answer.

Comment: This is the answer that I found easiest to understand, although @KeyIdeas gives good illustration and alternate applications of the basic principle at work.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint** $\ $ Key idea: $\,\color{#0a0}{\rm descent}$ follows by taking the $\,\rm\color{#c00}{FP\, (fractional\  part)}\,$ of equal fractions, e.g. $\,\frac{42}{10} = \frac{63}{15}\,\stackrel{\color{#c00}{\rm FP}}\Rightarrow\, \frac{2}{10 }= \frac{3}{15}\ $ by subtracting from both their integer part $= 4.\,$  Applying this below

$$\sqrt{N}\, = \frac{N}{\sqrt{N}}\, \Rightarrow\, \frac{A}B = \frac{NB}{A}\ \color{#c00}{\stackrel{\rm FP}\Rightarrow}\, \frac{b}B = \frac{a}A\, \Rightarrow\, \frac{A}B = \frac{a}{b}\ \ \ {\rm for}\ \ \ \begin{eqnarray}\color{#0a0}{0<a<A} \\ 0<\,b<B\end{eqnarray}$$

where $\,a,b\ne 0,\,$ else $\,\sqrt{N} = A/B\,$ has zero fractional part, i.e. it is an integer, contra hypothesis.
Hence, by descent: $ $ given any fraction $ = \sqrt{N}\,$ there is one with smaller numerator $\,\color{#0a0}{a < A}.\,$ Or, contrapositively, by complete induction: if no  $\ a < A\,$ is a numerator for $\,\sqrt{N}\,$ then neither is $\,A.$

**Remark** $\ $ The classical proof in Michael Hardy's answer is a special case since, for fractions in the interval $\,[1,2),\,$ taking the fractional part $(\color{#c00}{\rm FP})$  amounts to $\,\color{#c00}{\rm subtracting\ 1},\,$ so, as above,

$$\sqrt{2}\, = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\, \Rightarrow\, \frac{A}B = \frac{2B}{A}\ \color{#c00}{\stackrel{\rm FP}\Rightarrow}\, \frac{A\!-\!B}B = \frac{2B\!-\!A}{A}\, \Rightarrow\, \frac{A}B = \frac{2B\!-\!A}{A\!-\!B}$$

The proof in Shaswata's answer is the classical proof by cancelling  $2,\,$ in fraction form, i.e.

$\quad\displaystyle \sqrt{2}\, = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\,\Rightarrow \frac{\color{#c00}A}B = \frac{2B}{A} = \frac{\color{#c00}B}{\color{#0a0}{A/2}}\,\ $  by $\ \displaystyle\left[\! \begin{eqnarray}  2B^2 = A^2&&\\ \ \Rightarrow\  \color{#0a0}{2\,\mid A}\  &&\end{eqnarray}\!\!\right].\ $  $\,\left[\begin{eqnarray}\\ {\rm So \ \ } \color{#c00}{A>B}\ \ \ {\rm by}&&\\ \sqrt{2}\, = \frac{A}B>1&&\end{eqnarray}\!\!\right]\Rightarrow\,$ descent.

The advantage of the first proof is that if one attempts to extend the prior proof to general square roots then one needs more power, viz. the prime divisor property: prime $\,p\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid a\,$ or $\,p\mid b,\,$ or some equaivalent, e.g. uniqueness of prime factorizations. However, the first proof uses only the division algorithm (conceptually it can be viewed as employing the continued fraction algorithm to prove the uniqueness of reduced fractions or, equivalently, Euclid's Lemma). The continued fraction algorithm is a variant of the Euclidean algorithm. The same methods will work in any domain that enjoys an analogous division with remainder algorithm, i.e. so-claeed Euclidean domains, e.g. any ring $\,F[x]\,$ of polynomials with coefficients in a field.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $(N_0+1)/b=\sqrt{2}$.  Then a bit of algebra shows that $\dfrac{2b-(N_0+1)}{N_0+1-b}=\sqrt{2}$, contradicting the induction hypothesis.

Comment: I think the way this particular proof is usually phrased is about like this: If $m/n=\sqrt{2}$ and the fraction is in lower terms (coprime integers) then $(2n-m)/(m-n)$ is also equal to $\sqrt{2}$ but is in even lower terms, so that's a contradiction.

Comment: It's a bit hard for me to see how you came up with that fraction and how do we know it's in lower terms?

Comment: Your second question is the easier one: We have $2b$ $=\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2}\, b)$ $=N_0+1$, so $2b-(N_0+1)$ $=\sqrt{2}(N_0+1)-(N_0+1)$ $=(\sqrt{2}-1)(N_0+1)$ $<N_0+1$.  If the numerator is smaller than in the other fraction, then so must be the denominator.  You could also apply a similar argument to the denominator.  To be continued.....

Comment: You can also show it's in _lower_ terms via geometry.  Look at this paper: http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~marin/une_autre_crypto/articles_et_extraits_livres/irationalite/Apostol_T._irationality...-.pdf

Comment: The geometric argument is how I came up with the other fraction.  I first read that geometric argument in a book by Otto Toeplitz before Tom Apostol's paper was published.  Apparently Apostol was unaware of the presentation of this argument in that book.

Comment: Now I'm wondering: If $m/n$ is a convergent in the simple continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt{2}$, is $(2n-m)/(m-n)$ the previous convergent?  It should be easy to answer that one quickly.

Comment: . . . . . I had assumed that to be the case, so now my thought is: Maybe that's another way to come up with this fraction in the first place, besides the argument from geometry.

Comment: @Mark I explain the idea behind this method in my answer - see the remark I just added.